# QTableWidget Left Click CustomContextMenu

Tags: c++, qt, contextmenu, qtablewidget

I have a `QTableWidget` that currently has it's own custom context menu. Here is the code used to set it up:

```
MyClass::MyClass()
{
    m_table->horizontalHeader()->setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::CustomContextMenu);

    connect(m_table->horizontalHeader(), SIGNAL(customContextMenuRequested(QPoint)), SLOT(customHeaderMenuRequested(QPoint)));
}

void MyClass::customHeaderMenuRequested(QPoint pos)
{
    int columnClicked = m_table->horizontalHeader()->logicalIndexAt(pos);

    QMenu * menu = new QMenu(this);
    actNone = new QAction("-", this);
    menu->addAction(actNone);
    .
    .
    .
    menu->popup(m_table->horizontalHeader()->viewport()->mapToGlobal(pos));
}
```

This context menu occurs when a user **right clicks** the column header of the `QTableWidget`.

I would like to replicate this behavior except that I want it to be a **left click** rather than a right click.

I've tried adding `EventFilter`s and other things but nothing has worked.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the `sectionClicked` signal of `QHeaderView`, so you must change the `customHeaderMenuRequested` argument from `QPoint` to `int`, this parameter will indicate the column pressed, to obtain the geometrical position `QCursor::pos()` is used:

```
MyClass::MyClass()
{
    ...
    connect(m_table->horizontalHeader(), &QHeaderView::sectionClicked, this, &MainWindow::customHeaderMenuRequested);

}

void MyClass::customHeaderMenuRequested(int section)
{
    qDebug()<<section;
    QMenu * menu = new QMenu(this);
    QAction *actNone = new QAction("-", this);
    menu->addAction(actNone);
    menu->popup(QCursor::pos());
}
```

---

**Update:**

A better solution is to implement a customized `QHeaderView`:

**headerview.h**

```
#ifndef HEADERVIEW_H
#define HEADERVIEW_H

#include <QHeaderView>
#include <QMouseEvent>

class HeaderView : public QHeaderView
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    using QHeaderView::QHeaderView;
protected:
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event){
        if(event->buttons() == Qt::LeftButton)
            emit customSignal(logicalIndexAt(event->pos()));
        QHeaderView::mousePressEvent(event);
    }
signals:
    void customSignal(int section);
};

#endif // HEADERVIEW_H
```

---

```
MyClass::MyClass()
{
    ...
    HeaderView *horizontal_header = new HeaderView(Qt::Horizontal);
    m_table->setHorizontalHeader(horizontal_header);
    connect(horizontal_header, &HeaderView::customSignal, this, &MainWindow::customHeaderMenuRequested);

}

void MyClass::customHeaderMenuRequested(int section)
{
    qDebug()<<section;
    QMenu * menu = new QMenu(this);
    QAction *actNone = new QAction("-", this);
    menu->addAction(actNone);
    menu->popup(QCursor::pos());
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be correct. One more question, is there a way to show this menu on `mousedown` rather than how it seems to be showing on `mouseup`?

Is there also a way to disable column highlighting when a column header is clicked?

Comment: @Sej 
let me see, I think I have a solution, I'll try it and I'll let you know.

Comment: Hi, when attempting your updated code I'm getting the errors: `error C2876: 'QHeaderView': not all overloads are accessible` which I looked up and can't see an issue with the code at all. Nothing is private and I even tried making the `protected` into `public` with no luck. I also get `error C2664: HeaderView::HeaderView`: cannot convert parameter 1 from `Qt::Orientation` to `const HeaderView &`. Im going to keep trying to fix it though

Comment: @Sej enable C++11: `CONFIG += c++11`, you could share your code, maybe the error is elsewhere.